# Share username password between site pages

Tags: html

I'm fairly new in web development. After googling a couple of hours i can't find a comprehensive answer. My question: what is the best way to share credentials between web pages; To explain that, after login procedure, user is directed to page A. Page A includes a form that connects to database. How can page A remember username and password from first login; Using sessionStorage or localStorage; What is the most secure way to do that; Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally you'd use sessions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the General procedure.

When user submits username and password, if authenticated, create a session variable(contains username as value for example).

Then check the session variable's value in all page. if the variable exists, user has logged in already, if not redirect to login page.

Optional : 
You can provide "remember me" feature with cookies.

http://www.bitrepository.com/php-autologin.html

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach may be cookie, keeping authenticated user id in cookie and caching more information about it in server side session and also some parts of information in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to create a session record in your database that has an encrypted/unguessable key (as well as any other user data- eg session create/expiry time and so on) and then you store this key in a cookie on the client

Comment: I am sure there are stacks of questions on this. Try searching for sessions

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Terms to google: `server-side sessions`, `web application authentication`.

Long story short, each of your requests from browser to server must contain special parameter holding some token of identity of the requester. This is fundamental.

JSON API endpoints usually requires special keys passed explicitly with each request. You do an "auth" request, which returns you a session key, and after that all your subsequent requests must hold this session key.

Usual web applications use implicit keys, hiding them in cookies.

Either way, each request is accompanied with the ID of the session, and session is managed on the server. For example it can be a record in database with timestamp and a time to live defined. Or it can be `SESSION` mechanics built-in to PHP.